# Is mixing future and past tense in this sentence correct?

Tags: tense, grammaticality

> 'It will take a while to locate a paperwork for 2 years ago'

I think this sentence sounds weird, future tense and past tense are mixed. Is this sentence correct?

Comment: will you please tell us at least the verbs which are in the past and in the future? The ones which are mixed?

Comment: The only verb form in the cited text is ***will take***. But there's nothing wrong with, say, *It **will take** a while to find out what **happened** yesterday*.

Answer (score 2):

Grammar purists would say that 'for' should be replaced with 'from', however this is reasonably common in general usage.

Expanding the last bit a little makes it much more normal, e.g. "... paperwork for something that happened two years ago."